# ng-grid paging: total items and page count is wrong

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ng-grid

I have followed several threads in here related to the issue but couldn't find the issue with my code. I have a paged ng-grid, but the total item count (bottom left corner) and the total page count x/n is wrong. When I should have 14 as total items and 3 as total pages for a page size of 5, I see the total count as 5 and the total pages as 1. However, I can navigate to the other pages with the arrow icon.

Here is my code:

```js
   vm.gridOptions = {
            data: "vm.pagedDataList",
            rowHeight: 35,
            enableCellSelection: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'locationId', displayName: localize.getLocalizedString('_LocationCode_'), visible: false},
                { field: 'locationCode', displayName: localize.getLocalizedString('_LocationCode_'), width: '10%', cellTemplate: tooltipTemplateUrl },
                { field: 'locationTypeName', displayName: localize.getLocalizedString('_Locationtype_'), width: '15%', cellTemplate: tooltipTemplateUrl },
                { field: 'locationName', displayName: localize.getLocalizedString('_LocationName_'), width: '15%', cellTemplate: tooltipTemplateUrl },
                { field: 'locationDisplayName', displayName: localize.getLocalizedString('_LocationDisplayName_'), width: '15%', cellTemplate: tooltipTemplateUrl }
            ],
            enablePaging: true,
            showFooter: true,
            pagingOptions: { pageSizes: [5,10], pageSize: 5, currentPage: 1 },
            totalServerItems: 'vm.locationList.length'
        };

        $scope.$watch('vm.gridOptions.pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            //if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
                vm.getPagedDataAsync(vm.gridOptions.pagingOptions.pageSize, vm.gridOptions.pagingOptions.currentPage, null);
            //}
        }, true);

        vm.setPagingData = function (data, page, pageSize) {
            var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
            vm.pagedDataList = pagedData;
            vm.gridOptions.totalServerItems = data.length;
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        };

        vm.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page) {
            vm.setPagingData(vm.locationList, page, pageSize);
        };
```

Then I call this in the init() method, after the data is loaded;

```
  vm.getPagedDataAsync(vm.gridOptions.pagingOptions.pageSize, vm.gridOptions.pagingOptions.currentPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

change line

```
   totalServerItems: 'vm.locationList.length'
```

to

```
   totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
```

and

```
  vm.gridOptions.totalServerItems = data.length;
```

to

```
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
```

Comment: This method is not updating the number of records for the first time before pagination is triggered. When pagination is triggered then the value becomes correct.